# Laravel: Changing elements on textbox edit

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.4

First Laravel Project.
I want to make a form where if I write something in a textbock (for example a barcode) the code searches in a database and prints out a value (for example the price)

My code is so far:

The view:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/product/$barcode'))}}
<script>
function showProduct(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","script/getproduct.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>

//If I don't set the @vars first I get "unknown variable" error
<?php $name=0; $price=0; ?>
<table>
<tr>
<td>{{Form::text('barcode', null, ['onchange'=>'showProduct(this.value)'])}}</td>
<td><div id="txtHint">Name: {{ $name }}</div></td>
<td><div id="txtHint">Price: {{ $price }}</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
{{Form::close()}}
```

The showproduct.php:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$sql = DB::select('select * from inventory where barcode = ? LIMIT 1', [$q]);

$price = $sql[0]->price;
$name = $sql[0]->name;
?>
```

But when I put a barcode to the textfield I still got 0 in the fields. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first issue , you are using multi ID in your DOM document, which is totally wrong .

```
<td><div id="txtHint">Name: {{ $name }}</div></td>
<td><div id="txtHint">Price: {{ $price }}</div></td>
```

must be as follows :

```
<td><div id="nameHint">Name: {{ $name }}</div></td>
<td><div id="priceHint">Price: {{ $price }}</div></td>
```

then, in your php side you will need to `echo` some data , and to send multiple data the best approach by encode it into json , then decode that json from your client side and parse it into DOM elements using javascript.

so , in your php code , modify it to be as follows :

```
$price = $sql[0]->price;
$name = $sql[0]->name;
echo json_encode(array("price" => $price, "name" => $name));
```

then from your client side , decode that json as follows :

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("priceHint").innerHTML = jsonObject['price'];
    document.getElementById("nameHint").innerHTML = jsonObject['name'];
}
```

Comment: I still got Name: 0 and Price: 0 if I write the barcode in the field

Comment: are you sure that there are a response came from your ajax response ? print your ajax response in your console and check what is there

Comment: I found an `ReferenceError: showProduct is not defined` error

Comment: replace this line `var jsonObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);` by : `console.log(this.responseText); var jsonObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);` then , open your browser console `CTRL + SHIFT + k` in firefox , and check the output

Comment: don't forget to refresh your page before that

Comment: output is empty

Comment: do you have php response ? check it with your network monitor

Comment: error 500 means that there are a issue in your php code, please update your question by the full/new php code

Comment: The code is what is in the question. Now I tried to delete the  <?php ?> It's now working, but at the console I got this:  `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: you can't delete <?php ?> , at the start of your php file put this lines to get your php errors , `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DB' not found in /var/www/project/leltar/public/script/getproduct.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>/public/script/getproduct.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />`

Comment: i think it's clear to you now ;) as long as you are using laravel, write a new controller to handle this instead of native php;

Comment: Thank you :) Can I have a last question before I chack it solved? How to pass the javascript to a controller instead of the native php?

Comment: it's really long to answer here, but you can create a controller, then point your javascript ajax to the route which is points to that controller